# How to append array of bytes to the existed StorageFile?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to write to a file data by chunks of bytes consequentially (in my Metro app) and there is a class `FileIO` with methods `AppendTextAsync` and `WriteBytesAsync` but without needed `AppendBytesAsync` so how can I append an array of bytes to a `StorageFile`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code seems to work for me:

```
String s = "hello";
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

using (Stream f = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync
    ("hello.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists))
{
    f.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    await f.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Another neat solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711453/appending-text-to-file-windows-store-apps-windows-rt