# Appending Text to File Windows store Apps (windows RT)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am looking for a way to append strings-text to a file in a Windows Store App. I have tried reading the file and then creating a new one to overwrite it but Windows Store Apps C# does not work like C where when creating a new file with the same name overwrites the old one. Currently my code is opening the old file, reading it's contents, deleting it and creating a new one with the content I read plus the content I wish to append. 
I know there is a better way but I cannot seem to find it. So How may I append text to an already existent file in a Windows Store App (Windows RT)?

EDIT--

I tried this

```
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("feedlist.txt");
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, s);
```

but I keep getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`
according to MSDN this happens when the file is readonly (I checked with right click properties, it's not) and if I do not have the necessary privileges to access the file
what should I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [FileIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) class to append to a file.  For example ...

```
// Create a file in local storage
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("temp.txt", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

// Write some content to the file
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "some contents");

// Append additional content
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "some more text");
```

Check out the [File Access Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597/) for more examples.

Comment: What happens if the file already exists? you have FailIfExists, what happens with that? the File already exists in my app (I use it as a startup input file)

Comment: @JohnDemetriou There are many CreationCollisionOption to choose.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx

Comment: I tried this
   var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("feedlist.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, s);
and nothing is appended to the file

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Do you get an exception?  Where is the file located?

Comment: The file is located in the app directory (I also added it in the solution as a resource). What does not work is the fact that the file stays the same

Comment: @JP_Alioto I tried different types of code and I keep getting no access rights exception. the file is located in the app folder

Comment: @JohnDemetriou You cannot access the package install location, only the app local folder.  In order to access files deployed with the package, you have to use the ms-appx:// protocol http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781215.aspx

Comment: but i can easily read the file that I inserted, I cannot alter it? check again my question if you haven't, I edited it with more details on what code I am using

Comment: @JohnDemetriou - Did you find a solution to this? Even I am trying to create a file in Localfolder of application and add lines to it. The file does get created but is blank i.e no data is written to it.

Comment: @Tulika I think I had. but it has been so long since then. It was even before Windows 8.1 APIs changed probably and also I cannot find the original code I wrote. Probably the answer posted here helped me and that is why I accepted it. But cannot really remember right now

Answer (score 1):

Using FileIO.AppendTextAsync is a good option.
Please find the code snippet for this.

- First it creates a folder, if not exists. Otherwise it will not  create.
- Then it creates a file if not exists.
- Finally appending the text in the file.

  ```
  public static async void  WriteTrace(TraceEventType eventType, string msg, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
  {
       const string TEXT_FILE_NAME = "Trace.txt";
      string logMessage = eventType.ToString() + "\t" + methodName + "\t" + msg ;
      IEnumerable<string> lines = new List<string>() { logMessage }; 
      StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
      StorageFolder tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

      //if(localFolder.CreateFolderQuery(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFolderQuery.)
      StorageFolder LogFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("LogFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

      await LogFolder.CreateFileAsync(TEXT_FILE_NAME, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

      StorageFile logFile = await LogFolder.GetFileAsync(TEXT_FILE_NAME);

      await FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(logFile, lines);

  }
  ```