# UWP - writing to JSON without owerwrite data

Tags: json, uwp

I want to write data to JSON file, without overwriting them. I am using this code

```
Item test = new Item("test", 23);

        try
        {
            var Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            //var file = await Folder.CreateFileAsync("data.json", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var file = await Folder.GetFileAsync("data.json");
            var data = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

            using (StreamWriter r = new StreamWriter(data))
            {
                var serelizedfile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
                r.Write(serelizedfile);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            throw a;
        }
```

Comment: Is there more code? You're just throwing away the stream.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append array of bytes to the existed StorageFile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092488/how-to-append-array-of-bytes-to-the-existed-storagefile)

Comment: I need to write whole instance of object Item (It will have a lot of more attributes). I don´t think, this is best option.

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't clear to me. What exactly are you trying to do? What is "them" you don't want to overwrite?

Comment: Ok, so ... in my UWP app, I have JSON file named data. To this file, I want to add instances of object Item (user will fill form ... name, prize etc...). I am using the code in main post. When I start app, fill the form (for example name: "bounty" and prize: 12) and save it, data will be in JSON file. When I fill another item (for example name: "chicken" and prize: 30) and save it, it will overwrite the JSON file. So in file is not record 1 (bounty) and 2(chicken), there is only chicken. And that´s a problem, I want to have in JSON file more records. Hope, you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that you're possibly using the [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization and deserialization the Json file. I think it's better to deserialize the list of Json object and you can operate on this list, then serialize the new list to Json and save into the file, not directly serialize one item and write it into the file.

For example, my Json file is like this:

```js
[
    {"color":"red","value":"#f00"},
    {"color":"green","value":"#0f0"},
    {"color":"blue","value":"#00f"},
    {"color":"cyan","value":"#0ff"},
    {"color":"magenta","value":"#f0f"},
    {"color":"yellow","value":"#ff0"},
    {"color":"black","value":"#000"}
]
```

code for adding one item to this file:

```cs
if (file != null)
{
    using (var streamIn = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(streamIn);
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)streamIn.Size);
        var jsonInstring = reader.ReadString((uint)streamIn.Size);
        var JobjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonColor>>(jsonInstring);
        reader.Dispose();
        JobjList.Add(new JsonColor() { color = "pink", value = "#c0c" });
        JsonOutstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JobjList);
    }
    using (var streamOut = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(streamOut);
        writer.WriteString(JsonOutstring);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}
else
{
}
```

My class object:

```cs
public class JsonColor
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I deserialized the Json file and get the `List<JsonColor>`, then I added one item `new JsonColor() { color = "pink", value = "#c0c" }` to this list, and finally serialized this new list and save it. So for your scenario, you can modify the Json file and my `JsonColor` class to fit your need.

**Update:**

```cs
private string JsonOutstring;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //create a json file, if the file is exit, then open it.
    var local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var Jsonfile = await local.CreateFileAsync("test.json", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    if (Jsonfile != null)
    {
        ReadAndWriteJsonFile(Jsonfile);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

public async void ReadAndWriteJsonFile(StorageFile file)
{
    using (var streamIn = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(streamIn);
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)streamIn.Size);
        var jsonInstring = reader.ReadString((uint)streamIn.Size);
        var JobjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonColor>>(jsonInstring);
        reader.Dispose();
        if (JobjList == null)
        {
            JobjList = new List<JsonColor>();
        }
        JobjList.Add(new JsonColor() { color = "pink", value = "#c0c" });
        JsonOutstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JobjList);
    }
    using (var streamOut = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(streamOut);
        writer.WriteString(JsonOutstring);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}

public class JsonColor
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks so good. But I have little problem there. On the line, where is JobjList.Add(new JsonColor() { color = "pink", value = "#c0c" }); it shows me error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I fix that ?

Comment: @Aellopos, did you create the JsonColor class in your code like I did?

Comment: Yes, I did. I´ve created a new project for testing this code.

Comment: @Aellopos, I'm not sure where is your problem, so I uploaded my demo [here](https://github.com/GraceFeng/UWPJsonIssues), you may take a look.

Comment: It doesn´t work too, but I know why. I work with empty JSON and it shows me the error. When i put there code from your JSON file, it works. So I must there have this braces []. Then it works. But I need to have my JSON file in local folder of my app. So how can I put there these braces, when I creating new JSON file ?

Comment: @Aellopos, it's actually similar, what you need is nearly only changing `FileOpenPicker` to create a file. I edited my answer to update my code, if you find it works, please mark this answer.

Comment: Hello, I have one more question. How can I delete a record from the JSON file ?

Comment: @Aellopos, it's same, read all data, turn to List of `JsonColor`, delete the item from this list and save the new list again.